# Как переименовать класс во всём проекте?

Tags: unity3d

Есть ли возможность не лазить по всему проекту в поисках что да где, а просто тыкнуть пару кнопочек, и что бы везде, где используется выбранный класс, его название переименовалось на новое?

Comment: в визуал студио вроде `Ctrl+Shift+R`. Ещё в nodepad++ можно так же) главное заменять в .cs, а не  .meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Визуалке меняешь и тыкаешь Alt + Enter, если я правильно понял суть вопроса.